# Dropdown submenu disappears before mouse cursor reaches it

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, submenu

My second question today. I don't seem to find the answer why the dropdown disappears before I can reach it with my mouse cursor.

```
http://www.liveaerosmith.com
```

The "1970s" button in the top menu has a submenu, but it can't be clicked because it disappears before the cursor can reach it.

Same behaviour on FF and Chrome.

Comment: Allow your `li` elements to occupy the full height of the navigation bar so that the end-user's cursor has a "gangway" to the dropmenu, also bring up the drop menu to reduce the gap between it and the navigation bar. Finally, slow down the element, reduce it's `top` value in the inactive state so that it doesn't have to shoot back up and the user has more time to get to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This image says it all:

[image]

so there's a clear gap between the element with the `:hover` state and the child `ul` item

you could create a transparent `:after` pseudo element on the hovered LI that will connect the elements and "fill" the gap.

**Or rather do it the proper way:**

```
.site-bar {
    border-top: solid 1px #ebebeb;
    border-bottom: solid 1px #ebebeb;
    /*padding: 13px 0;                  REMOVE THIS */
    z-index: 10000000;
}

.navigation > li > a {
    margin-right: 30px;
    padding: 13px 0;                   /* ADD THIS */
}

.navigation li:hover > ul, .navigation .sfHover > ul {
    top: 44px;                         /* INSTEAD OF 34px */
}
```

Comment: What can I do to "fill the gap" without changing much of how it looks?

Comment: the simplest is to use a `:after` pseudo on the hovered LI. So on hover you "activate" (`display: block`) some `:after` element that will connect the gap (say those ~20px height and 100% width) and as such will keep the hover state for the hovered LI element.

Comment: It can work without adding a pseudo element. Here's how it should work:
https://www.cssigniter.com/preview/olsenlight

Comment: @Mr.Fontastic using JS? Do you really believe JS is needed for something you can fix using CSS?

Comment: I'm a newbie, sir, don't get mad. I took that theme and somehow managed to break the dropdown menu when changing some CSS. So it has to be a CSS thing, I didn't mess with the JS.